# Android Studio can't read json file

Tags: json, libgdx

When I run the app on my device I get no errors in the console and no background is showing up. However if I open the json it's almost all red. What can be wrong?

```
{
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
    white: { r: 1, g: 1, b: 1, a: 1 },
    black: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1 },
    gray:  { r: 0.3, g: 0.3, b: 0.3, a: 1 },
    red:   { r: 1, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1 },
    green: { r: 0, g: 1, b: 0, a: 1 },
    blue:  { r: 0, g: 0, b: 1, a: 1 }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: {
    white64: { file: font/white64.fnt }, 
    black64: { file: font/black64.fnt },
    white32: { file: font/white32.fnt },
    black32: { file: font/black32.fnt },
    white16: { file: font/white16.fnt },
    black16: { file: font/black16.fnt }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
    default: { font: white32, fontColor: white },
    big:     { font: white64, fontColor: white },
    small:   { font: white16, fontColor: white }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
    default: { up: button.up, down: button.down, font: black32, pressedOffsetX: 1, pressedOffsetY: -1 },
    big:     { up: button.up, down: button.down, font: black64, pressedOffsetX: 1, pressedOffsetY: -1 },
    small:   { up: button.up, down: button.down, font: black16, pressedOffsetX: 1, pressedOffsetY: -1 }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List$ListStyle: {
    default: { font: white32, fontColorUnselected: white, fontColorSelected: black, selection: default.selection }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane$ScrollPaneStyle: {
    default: { hScrollKnob: button.up, vScrollKnob: button.up }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.CheckBox$CheckBoxStyle: {
    default: { font: white32, checkboxOn: checkbox.on, checkboxOff: checkbox.off, checkboxOver: checkbox.over }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField$TextFieldStyle: {
    default: { font: black32, fontColor: black, messageFontColor: gray, background: default.background, cursor: default.selection }
}
}
```

This is how I call the json file:

```
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("ui/menuSkin.json"), new TextureAtlas("ui/atlas.pack"));
```

What Android Studio says when I hover my mouse over the errors:

```
JSON standard does not allow identifiers 
This inspection checks that JSON files conform to language specification  (RFC-7159)
```

Comment: Having this too, learned to work with it. You can turn Json inspections off in settings->editor->inspections but the `.`. and some other special characters will still be marked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to [RFC-7159](https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc7159.pdf) chapter no. 7 *Strings*

> The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the C
>    family of programming languages. **A string begins and ends with
>    quotation marks**.

And that's why probably the Android Studio is not validating this .json. In fact it should work since even the official examples do not respect this requirement - [take a look here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin).

---

I'm also not sure about using dots '**.**' in json entries'es values - for example: `checkboxOff: checkbox.off, checkboxOver: checkbox.over`. Ido not know if it will cause an error here but for me it seems to be not good practice.

In such situations I used to use underline '**_**' sign.